# Multiplicar 3 matrices con numpy - True False según se pueda o no

Tags: python, numpy, matriz

Necesito crear un código que me diga si puedo o no multiplicar 3 matrices con numpy y que me de True si se puede o False si no se puede.

```
m1 = np.asarray(m1)
m2 = np.asarray(m2)
m3 = np.asanyarray(m3)

if m1.shape[] != m2.shape[] != m3.shape[]:
    False 
    return None
else:
     True
     np.matmul(m1, m2, m3)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buen día,

El atributo [`numpy.ndarray.shape`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.shape.html) devuelve una tupla se utiliza sin corchetes, de la siguiente forma:

```
m1.shape
```

Por otra parte, para que el código te "diga" o te "devuelva" alguna respuesta se debe imprimir (`print()`) o retornar si creaste una función (`return`)

En tu caso como no se crea una función para que puedas obtener una respuesta del código habría que imprimirla

```
m1 = [[1,2],[3,4]]
m2 = [[5,6],[7,8]]
m3 = [[9,10],[11,12]]

m1 = np.asarray(m1)
m2 = np.asarray(m2)
m3 = np.asarray(m3)

if m1.shape == m2.shape == m3.shape:
    print(True)
    print(np.matmul(m1, m2, m3))
else:
    print(False)
```

Si las tres matrices tienen la misma forma entonces imprime `True`, realiza la operación e imprime el resultado.